# How to load a png image into a TImage

Tags: delphi

I am trying to load a png image into a TImage with Delphi XE4. The png starts off in a stream: E.g.

```
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Stream.LoadFromFile('c:\file.png');
    Stream.Position := 0;
    Image1.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
```

I get an AV when I run this code. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you do some debugging? We don't knoiw where the AV is. You can reproduce it? You should be more concerned with learning basic debugging skills than this specific problem

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `TImage.Picture.Graphic` property is nil until you load a graphic into the `Picture`.

What you are asking for can be achieved as follows:

```
  uses pngimage;

  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // obtain png image, load from file or other..
    ....
    Image := TPngImage.Create;
    try
      Stream.Position := 0;
      Image.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Image1.Picture.Graphic := Image;
    finally
      Image.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: I am using delphi 5 where there is no PNGImage file/dcu available. Can u please tell me how I can do the same with Memory stream.

Comment: See if you can install this [PngComponents](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cubicexplorer/downloads) for D5. If I recall correctly there is a TPNGObject in the package not TPNGImage.

Comment: You could load directly from png once it also can load from file.

Comment: Rael: That's right. I use D7 and PNG Delphi 1.56 by Gustavo Daud. For this I use TPNGImage.